# How to add ASP.NET and web development package to existing visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, visual-studio-2015

I was given a system with Visual studio installed. Below are the details.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Integrated)
Version 14.0.25420.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02053
```

Now there is a requirement for Developing a REST Web Service using C#. I wanted to use Visual Studio for that. But I couldn't find the web option. I have checked in `"File ->  New -> Project" and selecting "ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework)"`. How to add this package separately to the existing visual studio? is it possible? I have no idea. I have searched everywhere and all I could find is installing this in fresh setup. Please help

Comment: use the visual studio installer, I expect

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you don't have it installed.
You can use Visual Studio Installer to install the needed tool to do your work.
[image: Visual Studio Installer example image]

This is an example of how the installer is like.
But since you want to do a REST API in .NET, you'll need to install `ASP.NET and web development`

I hope it helped you! You can further more explore all the options available that you can download and use!